# Can't access database in Azure Portal - "This resource was not found"

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have an SQL database in Azure that I use with my API. I can access the database from SQL Server Management Studio, and it seemto be alright - I can select data, make modifications and whatever. Although, I can't access it from Azure Portal.

- It doesn't appear when I list all resources in the Azure portal
- When I select the database server from Azure Portal, I can see it under the list of available databases. When I click the specific database, I get the following error message:

"This resource was not found, it may have been deleted. /subscriptions/aee8966e-5891-40fb-8fff-8c359f43baee/resourceGroups/TestResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/testdbserver/databases/testdb"

Any ideas?

**Update 2018-05-16:**
Jerry Liu suggested renaming the database, so I logged into SQL Server Management Studio, and this is what I found:

1. I wasn't allowed to rename any of the databases on the server using right click --> Rename. The option is disabled.
2. ALTER DATABASE carbonate_prod_180508 Modify Name = carbonate_renamed;
   Running this command, I get the error message "The source database 'carbonate_prod_180508' does not exist.". But I do see the database listed in the Object Explorer.

I also tried renaming it using Azure CLI. I find the database using "az sql db list" with the resource group name and server name, but when i run "az sql db rename" I get an error message stating the database was not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have done some operation like delete and recreate with same name or just move to another resource group, please wait a while for the operation to work completely.

Or if you have done nothing related, please try to rename your database in Management Studio and visit portal to check whether it's "back".

**How to Rename SQL DB**

Two methods for you to try

- Click on database name twice slowly, or click once and push F2, just like we rename a file locally on Windows.
- Create query on `master` database to execute alter operation.

Wait for about 30 seconds and refresh portal.

If none of them works, I recommend you to new a support request to Azure Team. It's the last blade in your Azure sql server panel.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Just updated my question above with the steps; i'm facing issues renaming the database

Comment: @AndreasV Sorry for my long delay of response, have updated my answer with solutions.

Comment: it works now, I can see the database in the portal after renaming it. Thank you!